# Angular - Prevent click event on disabled buttons

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom-events

I'm trying to prevent click event on disabled buttons, in other words, prevent some user who removes the disabled attribute to call some action.

For now, I have the following code to do this:

```html
<button [disabled]="someCondition" (click)="executeAction()">Execute action</button>
```

```
executeAction(): void {
  if (this.someCondition) return;

  // ...
}
```

Works, but it isn't a good solution as I have to do it for ALL buttons in my app (and believe me, it's easy to forgot to do this and even a *Linter* can't help me here).

Looking for a more robust solution, I thought that `directive` could help me:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input, Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'button'
})
export class ButtonDirective {
  @Input() set disabled(value: boolean) {
    this._disabled = value != null;
    this.renderer2.setAttribute(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'disabled', `${this._disabled}`);
  }

  private _disabled: boolean;

  constructor(
    private readonly elementRef: ElementRef,
    private readonly renderer2: Renderer2
  ) { }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(mouseEvent: MouseEvent) {
    // nothing here does what I'm expecting
    if (this._disabled) {
      mouseEvent.preventDefault();
      mouseEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
      mouseEvent.stopPropagation();

      return false; // just for test
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button [disabled]="someCondition" (click)="executeAction()">Execute action</button>
```

```
executeAction(): void {
  console.log('still being called');
}
```

...however it does absolutely nothing. It doesn't prevent the `click` event. Is there any solution that I don't have to control the action itself in its call?

[***STACKBLITZ***](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhyu2b)

Comment: dev_054 did my ans helped?

Answer (score 2):

This is a workaround with CSS which cheaper than scripts.

You easily could use

```
pointer-events: none;
```

In this case, the button will not be clickable.

As a UX enhance you could also wrap your button inside a *div* and give this div a CSS property

```
cursor: not-allowed;
```

Which will show the blocked circle icon instead of normal mouse view when hover.

Comment: this did the trick <a mat-button (click)="addWizard()" [ngStyle]="{'pointer-events': (groupsAccessTable$ | async).add !== false ? 'none' : ''}"
                       [disabled]="(groupsAccessTable$ | async).add !== true">
                        <mat-icon>auto_fix_high</mat-icon>
</a>

Answer (score 1):

In your directive, you can do something like this. You can achieve it by adding an event listener to parent in the capturing phase.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
      if(this._disabled && e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
    }, true);
  }
```

You can remove the listener in `onDestroy`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's an interesting solution, however it prevents ANY click on parent, even a div with `click`, for example. Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yonrls

Comment: Yup, got that, but if you can wrap your button in a div or any other tag. That would solve the prob.

Comment: updated the answer with one more sanity to check if targe is BUTTON or not.

Answer (score 0):

In our project, the following worked to prevent the click event for a disabled button without having to define your own custom events:

Component template:

```
<button class="btn"
[disabled]="disabled || inProgress">
<span (click)="disabled ? $event.stopPropagation() : undefined">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</span>
</button>
```

Works for usage:

```
<app-button (click)="onClick()">
<span>Click me</span>
</app-button>
```

Answer (score -1):

> Prevent click event on disabled buttons

If the `disabled` attribute is there the click will not happen.

## When user decides to use devtools

However if the user edits the HTML and removes the disabled attribute manually, then click will happen. You can try and do the check as you have suggested, but the browser is an unsafe environment. The user will still be able to execute any code on the webpages behalf irrespective of any *frontend* checks you might put in.

Comment: Hey @basarat, yep, I know that `click` isn't triggered for `disabled` buttons, if you don't use devtools, however the OP IS exactly about it. I'm looking for a solution different to what I presented. I don't want to control it on each component. Let me know if the question isn't clear.

Comment: This is right, thats why this has to be controlled in the api.